# How to publish Web Api

Tags: c#, api

I'm developing a simple Web Api that writes on Firebase DB. I'm using very simple tutorial found on web. API works in localhost.

Now I would like to publish API on my hosting (I have an account here, just for test: https://freeasphosting.net )

I've tried to follow this very simple tutorial on microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/mac/publish-folder?view=vsmac-2019

Now I have folder with a lot of file (dll, json and web.config).

- What should I do with this file? Do I just have to upload on root by FTP?
- What kind of settings are necessary in file launchsettings.json in VS solution? Now I use these settings, and in localhost API works

  ```
  {
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50798",
        "sslPort": 0
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "api/values",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "usersAPI": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "api/values",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5008"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: You should try to learn the settings as defined, which will help you further in customizations. Also the documents on - https://freeasphosting.net/login-system-exercise.html explains very well to host your web api.

Comment: Sorry but it seems there’s nothing, on link you wrote, that answer to my questions

Answer (score 0):

Edit all the necessary part of your application before publishing it and then upload all those dlls in the root folder of your hosting account.

Comment: what necessary parts?

Comment: Like connectionstring to the database if you are connected to any.

Answer (score -1):

I am honestly not familiar with this service, so I'm not sure about it specifically.  Generally speaking the file folder with you web.config, and all the dlls is what you would upload if you were using an IIS server for instance.  That is what you will want to upload to the root of your site.  Having that said, my advice would be to use Azure for this.  They have a good free tear for development, and working with Azure itself is a marketable skill.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Like you said (and like other tutorials says) I tried to do that (so publish in folder and then upload files) but I got 500 - Internal server error. So I think there are some errors in launchsettings file but I don’t understand what kind of changes are necessary

Comment: I would start with a minimal website and publish/upload that first. That way you will know if your process is correct. Once you have established that, move up to your real project.